# Mouse right clicking really fast by itself

Tags: windows-10, mouse, right-click

Hi i have a Razer Deathadder and i have been experiencing problems that render it impossible for me to use my computer unless i restart.
I have been playing Fortnite and in the middle of a game my right click button stops working then when i click onto my desktop it seems to be clicking on its own, i have run a Norton full system scan and it came up with nothing as well as trying a different mouse but same problem. And where I've been looking it all comes back to reinstalling windows but i'd like to keep my data so i was just checking if anyone had another idea if not can someone tell me how to reinstall windows without losing my data. Thanks :)

Comment: do you have any other game controllers plugged in?  a racing wheel, HOTAS, etc.?

Comment: No, i dont i only have a mouse and keyboard plugged in.